# How to profile an AJAX endpoint in Flask?

Tags: flask, profiling

To profile a GET endpoint in Flask, I've been using the [Line Profile Panel for Flask Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/jlfwong/flask_debugtoolbar_lineprofilerpanel).

This doesn't work on AJAX/XHR endpoints though.  I've also tried [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) but it doesn't play nice with Flask.

Comment: Then use [Flask-Debug-API](https://github.com/kevinbeaty/flask-debug-api) to use show the debug toolbar on AJAX endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: this only works if you're loading pages through Flask, not if you're only using Flask for AJAX endpoints.

Martijn Pieters' comment is correct.  You can use [Flask-Debug-API](https://github.com/kevinbeaty/flask-debug-api) together with the Line Profiler Panel (https://github.com/jlfwong/flask_debugtoolbar_lineprofilerpanel).

Once both are added to your code, then you can navigate through the API Browser to the endpoint you want to test, submit a request to it, then you will have access to the results of the line profiler.